# Is it possible to compile ros c++ package to jars library using catkin?

Tags: catkin, roscpp, rosjava, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i have to create a robot_state_publisher  rosjava package.  So i am thinking whether there is a fast way to do this.

Any suggestions will be grateful.  Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218858/is-it-possible-to-compile-ros-c++-package-to-jars-library-using-catkin?/) by [erikcong80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24318/erikcong80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are [some tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk) that are actually targeted for Android but they basically do what you need. The difference is that they are doing a cross-compilation of the C++ code for an ARM target processor. Then there are several steps that show how to wrap the native code and load it in your java application. If you carefully take out the Android related stuff you should be able to get the needed functionality.

---

Originally posted by [Ernesto Corbellini](https://answers.ros.org/users/23887/ernesto-corbellini/) with karma: 101 on 2015-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1